# How can I load Debian onto a USB stick on Windows

Tags: debian

I have read the Debian documentation, specifically http://wiki.debian.org/BootUsb and http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb but they do not provide info on how to do it on Windows. So, how can I write a Debian image to a USD stick on Windows? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A friend of mine also said that running Linux from a thumbdrive can wreck your Windows HDD. Any proof to that claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) might be able to do it (at least, it claims to be able to create a Debian USB drive).

> UNetbootin allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu, Fedora, and other Linux distributions without burning a CD. It runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X. You can either let UNetbootin download one of the many distributions supported out-of-the-box for you, or supply your own Linux .iso file if you've already downloaded one or your preferred distribution isn't on the list.

Comment: Nice. I'll have to check that out!

Answer (score 1):

U can also try out [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com).
It has very user friendly interface